# Ruby program which sorts images into different directories by their names?

Tags: ruby, sorting, design-patterns, classification

I would like to make a Ruby program which sorts the images in the current directory into different subfolders, for example:

```
tree001.jpg, ... tree131.jpg -> to folder "tree"
apple01, ... apple20.jpg -> to folder "apple"
plum1.jpg, plum2.jpg, ... plum33.jpg -> to folder "plum"
```

and so on, the program should automagically recognize which files belong together by their names. I have no clue how to achive this. Till now I make a small program which collect the files with command "Dir" into an array and sort it alphabetically to help finding the appropriate classes by the file names. Does anybody have a good idea?

Comment: We have lots of ideas how to do it, but none will fit into the code you've written unless you show us what you wrote. Please add your code to the question by editing it, and we'll be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Find:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html

Or Dir.glob:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob

For instance:

```
Dir.glob("*.jpg")
```

will return an array that you can iterate with `each`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every file name starts with non-digit characters followed by at least one digit character, and the initial non-digit characters define the directory you want the file moved to:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob("*").select{|f| File.file? f}.each do |file| # For each regular file
  dir = file.match(/[^\d]*/).to_s              # Determine destination directory
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)                       # Make directory if necessary
  FileUtils.mv(file, dir)                      # Move file
end
```

The directories are created if necessary.  You can run it again after adding files.  For example, if you added the file `tree1.txt` later and re-ran this, it would be moved to `tree/` where `tree001.jpg` through `tree131.jpg` already are.

**Update:** In the comments, you added the requirement that you only want to do this for files which form groups of at least 10.  Here's one way to do that:

```
require 'fileutils'

MIN_GROUP_SIZE = 10

reg_files = Dir.glob("*").select{|f| File.file? f}
reg_files.group_by{|f| f.match(/[^\d]*/).to_s}.each do |dir, files|
  next if files.size < MIN_GROUP_SIZE

  FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir)

  files.each do |file|
    FileUtils.mv(file, dir)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx, function group_by is the key, I think, because there may be such files in the directory which form only one-element set, or two-, three-element set. And I want to select out those files which form at least a 10-element set.

Comment: @Konstantin  Okay, I've added an update demonstrating one way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it something like this:

```
files = %w[
  tree001.jpg tree03.jpg tree9.jpg
  apple1.jpg apple002.jpg
  plum3.jpg plum300.jpg
].shuffle
# => ["tree001.jpg", "apple1.jpg", "tree9.jpg", "plum300.jpg", "apple002.jpg", "plum3.jpg", "tree03.jpg"]

grouped_files = files.group_by{ |fn| fn[/^[a-z]+/i] }
# => {"tree"=>["tree001.jpg", "tree9.jpg", "tree03.jpg"], "apple"=>["apple1.jpg", "apple002.jpg"], "plum"=>["plum300.jpg", "plum3.jpg"]}

grouped_files.each do |grp, files|
  Dir.mkdir(grp) unless Dir.exist(grp)
  files.each { |f| FileUtils.mv(f, "#{grp}/#{f}") }
end
```

I can't test that because I don't have all the files, nor am I willing to generate them.

The important thing is [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). It makes it easy to group the similarly named files, making it easy to walk through them.

For your case, you'll want to replace the assignment to `files` with [`Dir.glob(...)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) or [`Dir.entries(...)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-entries) to get your list of files.

If you want to separate the file path from the file name, look at [`File.split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-split) or [`File.dirname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-dirname) and [`File.basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-basename):

```
File.split('/path/to/foo')
=> ["/path/to", "foo"]
File.dirname('/path/to/foo')
=> "/path/to"
File.basename('/path/to/foo')
=> "foo"
```